# How to test if calling process is a fork

Tags: c, linux, fork, exec, posix

Is there a method or C api in Linux/POSIX to determine if the current process is a fork? I.e. if it has been created by calling `fork()` without a subsequent call to the `execve()` family?

I do not control the code leading up to this point (it runs within a high-level language binding). I just need to know if the current process is running the top level program, or in a fork thereof.

The best I have come up with is testing if the process has the same gid as it's parent:

```
int is_fork = getpgid(0) == getpgid(getppid());
```

However this only works if the parent has called `setpgid()` which apparently `execve()` does not do by default. So that results in a lot of false positives.

Comment: Do you control the program? If yes, the only way to find out something like this I can think of would be to have a status variable set in the forked child process after `fork()`.

Comment: Your wording is a bit strange. **every** process (except init) is created by `fork()` So possibly your question should be: is my process a process group leader?

Comment: @wildplasser I am not familiar with terminology indeed. But I think the process group leader is the ancestor proc who called `setpgid()`, not the one calling `exec()`?

Comment: exec() is not relevant here. The process is replaced by a different image, but basically stays the same. Only a few things change (mainly memory mappings and signal-settings)

Comment: BTW: there is a semimicolon  missinng from your ` int is_fork = getpgid(0) == getpgid(getppid())` Just saying ...

Comment: @jeroen: what is the oroblem you really want to solve?

Answer (score 2):

If you can control the environment of the top-level executable, you can use `LD_PRELOAD` to preload a shared library that installs a `pthread_atfork` handler that marks the child as forked by setting a globally visible variable. Your test code can then check the value of the variable to find out if the process has been forked without an intervening `exec`.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, one somewhat imprecise check would be to see if the process's executable (`/proc/$pid/exe`) is the same as that of its parent. However, that won't work if a process `exec`s its own executable, which might be common in some environments (eg. shells).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw your answer! I deleted mine. Please forgive me.

Comment: @jean-baptiste: no worries. Not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `tms_utime`, `tms_stime`, `tms_cutime`, or `tms_cstime`  (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html). These variables are set to `0` in the child process.

*untested*

Comment: They are set to 0 at fork, but they don't remain zero as the process continues running. Also, this doesn't distinguish between `fork()` and `fork()` followed by `exec()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
/* ppid.c
cc -Wall ppid.c -o ppid
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int pid, ppid, pgid;

pid = getpid();
ppid = getppid();
pgid = getpgid(0);

printf("[%s] Pid=%d Ppid=%d Pgid=%d\n"
        , argv[0], pid, ppid, pgid);

return 0;
}
```

---

```
/* testppid.c
cc -Wall testppid.c -c testppid
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
int pid, pid2; 

pid = fork();
if (pid == -1) return 1;

if (pid) { /* parent */
        char *args[] = { "Parent", NULL};
        sleep(3);
        execve("./ppid", args, NULL);
} else { /* child */

        pid = getpid();
        setpgid(pid,pid);
        pid2 = fork();
        if (pid2 == -1) return 1;

        if (pid2) { /* child1 */
                char *args[] = { "Child1", NULL};
                sleep(2);
                execve("./ppid", args, NULL);

        } else { /* grandchild */
                char *args[] = { "Child2", NULL};
                sleep(1);
                execve("./ppid", args, NULL);
                }
        }

return 0;
}
```

---

Output:

---

```
$ ./testppid
[Child2] Pid=6220 Ppid=6219 Pgid=6219
[Child1] Pid=6219 Ppid=6218 Pgid=6219
[Parent] Pid=6218 Ppid=27410 Pgid=6218
$
```

---

This indicates that the shell (pid=27410) basically does the same to the Parent process as Child1 does before it invokes Child2: {fork,setpgid,exec}. Child1 is the proces group leader for itself and Child2 (the grandchild)